# How to include an external code file?

Tags: listings, debugging, eurosym

I have the following file structure:

```
File
|-urlaubsfahrt.py
|-Test
  |-test.tex
```

And the following tex file:

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{listings}

\begin{document}
\lstinputlisting[language=Python]{../urlaubsfahrt.py}
\end{document}
```

I want to include the source code of urlaubsfahrt.py file in my final pdf, but this throws the error that `Package utf8x Error: Character172appearedalone.`, because of the line `l.123 ...r(ceil(completePaid * 100)/100) + " €")`. I think this is because of the € sign. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`eurosym` provides the official Euro symbol through the `\euro` command and `textcomp` does it with `\texteuro`. Knowing that you can use the following approach, which works for me:

```
\usepackage[official]{eurosym}   
\lstset{literate={€}{{\euro{}}}1}
```